# Creating an array of images on a canvas

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, android-canvas

I am trying to create an array of images that can be drawn on a canvas. This is what I have:

```
List<Integer> imageHolder = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
imageHolder.add((int)R.drawable.bus_1);
imageHolder.add((int)R.drawable.bus_2);
imageHolder.add((int)R.drawable.bus_3);
```

Then I try and access the images like this from my onDraw method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);


        for (int i = 0; i < imageHolder.size(); i++){


            canvas.drawBitmap(imageHolder.get(i), 0, 0, null);
        }


    }
```

But I get an error saying that my arguments are not applicable for my canvas.drawbitmap. Does anyone know how to do this?I have been looking all over for an explanation on how to do this and I can't find it anywhere.

EDIT: This is how I got it working to print out the 3 images at different points on the screen:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageHolder.size(); i++) {
    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, imageHolder.get(0));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bMap, 100, 100, null);
    bMap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, imageHolder.get(1));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bMap2, 500, 100, null);
    bMap3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, imageHolder.get(2));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bMap3, 900, 100, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is you initially add a bunch of **integers** to an ArrayList and then you try to loop through this ArrayList and draw a Bitmap, using a resource identified by this integer. The problem is that the first argument to the `drawBitmap` method in the `Canvas` class must be either an integer array of colors or a Bitmap resource. Not just an integer, pointing to one. For more information, [check the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

In order to get a specific resource by ID as Bitmap you need to do this:

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable_id);
```

Or in your case your loop needs to look like this:

```
Resources res = getResources(); // Cache them
Bitmap bMap;
for (int i = 0; i < imageHolder.size(); i++){
    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, imageHolder.get(i));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant this is what i was looking to do.Thanks.Is there a way of changing where each image is drawn on the screen cos at the moment they are all been drawn at point 0,0?

Comment: Please, take a look at the documentation link I have provided in my answer. It explains in detail which parameters you can use for `drawBitmap`, including a Rect object, X/Y coordinates, a Mesh, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Lol! Check [`canvas.drawBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) The first parameter is a Bitmap object, while you only have the integers that point to the resource.

You can use:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), imageHolder.get(i)), 0, 0, null);
```